# Why when I add an image in my CSS/HTML code, it tiles it over and over again?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to say is that when I want to add an image, it does it over and over again, like this:

(I'm making a Frogger game btw using js/css/html)
You might have to zoom in to see it.

[Frogger Tiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwfY.png)

How can I make it without that? I want to do this:

[Frogger Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ztu1.png)

Any help will be appreciated. I think the problem is in the CSS. Also, answer my other question: Is it because I didn't add padding or a margin?

Here is my code:

```css
/* frog */
.frog {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  background-image: url(https://www.smspower.org/uploads/Sprites/Frogger-GG-Frog-Toberescued.png);
}
```

Also, please don't think about the background color thing. It's fine and I want it there.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the image is smaller than the background so to cover up the space it repeated it self.

Add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to the `.frog`:

```
/* frog */
.frog {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  background-image: url(https://www.smspower.org/uploads/Sprites/Frogger-GG-Frog-Toberescued.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

> Is it because I didn't add padding or a margin?

#### No!

---

To increase the size of the image add `background-size: [size];`:

The size can be anything like: `50%`, `80px`, `2rem`.

```
/* frog */
.frog {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  background-image: url(https://www.smspower.org/uploads/Sprites/Frogger-GG-Frog-Toberescued.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: it worked! also do you know how I can make it just a little bigger?

Comment: @DiveInsideTech Do you want to cover the whole container or make it a little big.

Comment: a little bit bigger? as in so that i can see because right now it looks like this:

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal try to give background-size to .frog for a little bigger image. Like background-size: 24px 26px;

Answer (score 0):

Because `background-repeat` is `repeat` by default. You should add to your code `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

```
/* frog */
.frog {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(https://www.smspower.org/uploads/Sprites/Frogger-GG-Frog-Toberescued.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i never knew this! if ur muslim - jzk allah!

Comment: do u know how i can make images transparent, but only the background of the image?

Comment: @DiveInsideTech you should change background-color: darkgreen; to background-color: transparent;

Comment: @DiveInsideTech edited of my code

Comment: thank you, but i already know that, but i figured it out now thank you so much however!